# Find minimum string cover by it's palindromic substrings

Tags: algorithms

Please, help me with the problem:

Given string containing Roman digits. My task is to find it's minimum palindromic coverage, s.t. each palindrom is correct Roman number. TL - 1s.

For example:
s = XXMMI (len(s) up to 1e5)
answer: {'XX', 'MM', 'I'}

What I've done:

1. Find all the palinromic substrings of s.
2. Filter them, checking that each of them is valid Roman number.
3. Find minimum cover of s by palindromic substrings obtained in 2nd step.

I'm struggling with the 3rd step. Can you help me, please?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "minimum palindromic coverage" with your example. Could you give a formal definition and/or other examples ?

Comment: Besides what is "TL - 1s" ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Palindromic coverage = minimum string cover by it's substrings s.t. each of them is palindrom. For example S = ABBAFXF, then ans = {'ABBA', 'FXF'}

Comment: @JeanMarie TL is time limit for program to execute (mostly in c++). It means that algorithm can't be worth than O(n^2)

Comment: Thanks for your answers. But you don't say what is to be "minimized" : is it the number of substrings, for example $2$ in $\{'ABBA', 'FXF'\}$ ?

Comment: Yes, the number of substrings!